# Finding limit supremum

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, complex-geometry, limsup-and-liminf

While  finding the limit supremum of $5x\cos(πx) - x^2$, the book says it is $-\infty$. But this function is bounded above. Shouldn't it's supremum be the lowest upper bound(which is 6). Why does it say it's supremum is $-\infty$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by $\limsup$? Usually there is a limit of something? Have you tried plotting the function?????

Comment: @copper.hat are you okay?????

Comment: Most people would say no :-).

Comment: It means limsup as x ---> $\infty$

Comment: and infact the lim as x-->$\infty$ is - $\infty$

Comment: The maximum value of $\cos(\pi x)$ is $1$, so $5x\cos(\pi x) -x^2\leq 5x-x^2$ when $x$ is positive. $5x-x^2$ has a global maximum at $x=5/2$, so it is bounded above. Your book is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $f(x)=5x\cos(πx) - x^2$ is continuos and

- $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} f(x)=-\infty$

then by EVT the function has maximum and is bounded from above.

Comment: Hi, but the function is bounded. So shouldn't its supremum be the lowest upper bound?

Comment: Yes but if we are looking for the limit supremum at infinity then limsup =liminf =$-\infty$.

Comment: But the limit superior(sorry for using supremum before) for a bounded sequence is it's lowest upper bound. We take the substitution at $\infty$ only if the sequence is unbounded(which is not in this case).

Comment: We should distinguish between supremum that in this case is the global maximum of f(x) and **limit supremum** at $\pm \infty$ that is $-\infty$.